# Error running: .\cloud_sql_proxy.exe for cloud sql connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, proxy, command, google-cloud-proxy

I recently got into developing with google cloud. Currently, I am working on connecting my app's backend to cloud SQL. I attempted to use the cloud SQL proxy to connect but I feel a bit confused with it.
When I run the command `.\cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=tcp:5432` while replacing the connection name I get the error `'.\cloud_sql_proxy.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I have named the file to just cloud_sql_proxy.exe. I also attempted to use just `cloud_sql_proxy.exe`. But still to no effect.

Comment: I provided you with an answer and documentation. The proxy file is not located in the Windows PATH or in the local directory `.\\`. Copy the file to a directory in your PATH or specify the full path name.

Answer (score 1):

When you download the Cloud SQL Proxy for Windows 64-bit, the file is named `cloud_sql_proxy_x64.exe`.

This first step is to copy the file to a location in your PATH or known directory and rename the file `cloud_sql_proxy.exe`.

[Download and install the Cloud SQL Auth proxy for Windows](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy#windows-64-bit)

Comment: I have tried that, any other suggestions as I think it has to do with the command itself?

Comment: @JoeCodes - Follow the documentation and download the file again.